# Java buildpack memory calculation

Tags: spring-boot, memory-management, buildpack

Java buildpack memory calculator with Spring Boot application inside of Docker container with 1GB memory calculates memory as it says in documentation, it takes entire available memory and this are calculated JVM options:

> Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx747490K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=157725K -Xss1M (Total Memory: 1G, Thread Count: 50, Loaded Class Count: 25433, Headroom: 0%)

Question is why does it takes entire available memory and gives it to JVM? It should leave some memory for java process outside of JVM. This can lead to OOM because JVM thinks it has 1GB for itself (747490K for heap), and in reality it has less because some of it's memory is used by native memory, outside of JVM.

Should I not use this calculator and set JVM configuration by myself or I can reconfigure this somehow?

Answer (score 3):

> Question is why does it takes entire available memory and gives it to JVM?

The assumption is that the only thing running in your container is your Java application, thus it assigns all of the available memory to be used.

If you do things like shell out and run other processes or run other processes in the container, you need to tell memory calculator so it can take that into account.

> This can lead to OOM because JVM thinks it has 1GB for itself (747490K for heap), and in reality it has less because some of it's memory is used by native memory, outside of JVM.

The memory calculator takes into consideration the major memory regions within a Java process. Not just heap. That said, it cannot 100% guarantee that you will never go over your memory limit. That's impossible with a Java app.

There are things you can do as an application developer, like create 10,000 threads or JNI, that cannot be restricted and could potentially consume a whole ton of memory. If you do that, your app will go over its container memory limit and crash.

The memory calculator attempts to give you a reasonable memory configuration for most common Java workloads. Running a web app, running a microservice, running some batch jobs, etc...

If you are doing something that doesn't fit within that pattern, then you can simply tell the memory calculator and it'll adjust things accordingly.

> Should I not use this calculator and set JVM configuration by myself or I can reconfigure this somehow?

Even if you need to customize what the calculator is doing it can be helpful. It's additional toil to calculate these values manually, especially when it's so easy to change the memory limits. If your ops team increases the memory limit of the container, you want your application to automatically adjust to that configuration (as well as it can).

Beyond that, memory calculator is also good at detecting problems early. If you configure the JVM manually and you mess it up, let's say you over-allocate memory, the JVM won't necessarily care until it tries to get more memory and can't. At some point down the road, you're going to have a problem but it's not clear when (probably at 3am on a Sat, lol).

With memory calculator, it's doing the math when your container first starts to make sure that memory settings are sane. If there's something off with the configuration, it'll fail and let you know.

TIPS:

1. You can override a memory calculator-defined value by simply setting that JVM option in the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` env variable. For example, if I want to allow for more direct memory, I would set `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=50M'`. Then when you restart the container, the memory calculator will shift memory around to accommodate that.
2. The one thing you don't want to set is `-Xmx`. The memory calculator should always set this because it will set it to whatever is left after other regions have been accounted for. You can think of it like `HEAP = CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT - (all static memory regions)`.

   If you were to set `-Xmx`, you have to get it exactly right. If it's too low then you're wasting memory. If it's too high then you could exceed the container memory limit and get crashes.

   In short, if you think you want to set `-Xmx`, you should either increase the container memory limit or decrease one of the static memory regions.
3. If you run other things in the container, you need to set the headroom. This is done with the `BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM` env variable. Give it a percent of the total container memory limit. Ex: `BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM=20` would use 80% of the container's memory limit for Java and 20 for other stuff.

   Setting some headroom can be useful in other cases as well, like if you're troubleshooting a container crash and you want a little extra room, or if you don't like operating at 100% the memory limit. You can leave 5 or 10% unused to match your comfort level.
4. If you have an application that uses a lot of threads, you'll need to adjust this as well. The default is 250 threads, which works well for many web/servlet-based applications (thread per request model). We do automatically lower to 50 threads if you're specifically using Spring Webflux which does not need so many threads.

   For other cases, it's up to you to configure this. For example, if you have a batch application that only needs a thread pool of 10, then you could set this 40 or 50. 40-50 seems weird in this example, but the JVM creates a number of its own threads and you need to account for those in addition to application-specific threads when in doubt look at a thread dump.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer it's werry helpful but I'm not running nothing else except Java application and assumption is never correct. If you give JVM 100% of memory Java process will over use that extra memory and it will lead to OOM in every case. If I have 1GB of memory, and calculator gives all 1GB to JVM, then JVM will potentially use it because it's the limit, and real memory inside container will be JVM + extra memory java process are using.

Comment: That's why I think you should always set -XMX and give less memory to JVM then your container limit is

Comment: If you have Oracle or OpenJDK reference docs you can share that explain what you're suggesting, I'd be happy to take a look and adjust the calculator as needed.